# Incomprehension in Java concatenation syntax

Tags: java, syntax, concatenation

Why does this code work correctly in Java? I have tried it in Eclipse and Itellij IDEA. The result is 8.

`int a = 3, b = 5;
 System.out.println(a + + b);`

Comment: Hint (assuming that `a` and `b` are numeric types): `System.out.println(+1); System.out.println(-1);`

Comment: Another thing : 99% of the time the IDE is unrelevant to the question. Some bugs are specific to the Eclipse-compiler (or specific to a non-Eclipse compiler) but that's very rare

Answer (score 1):

In java, `+` plays many roles according to the type of variables it is acting on. For numeric variables `+` is a binary and also a unary operator.
So in your statement

```
System.out.println(a + + b);
```

the compiler consider `+b` as an expression with the unary operator `+` (which does nothing), and then add `a` to that expression using the other `+` that is consider now as a binary operator. To better understand this, you should read about the priority of operators.